# PMSG connected to three-phase PWM rectifier - Simulink

Tags: rectifier, current-source, three-phase

I am implementing a controller for a three-phase rectifier in order to have a constant DC-link voltage.

I have a PMSG which is connected to the rectifier and a capacitor (DC-link); I want to model PMSG such that I have currents as output and, so, they will be input for the inverter.

So I will have a three-phase current source which I'll connect to the rectifier, but it isn't working properly due to the impossibility to connect three current sources in series or, simply, all electrical quantities blow up (they reach values of 10<sup>230</sup>).

If I model the PMSG with voltages as output (but I have to use a derivative block instead of integrators) all works properly.

In literature I have never encountered a three-phase rectifier with a current source, but I should avoid the use of derivative block for PMSG and work with currents instead of voltages. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Treating it as a current source is likely to cause some issues, as you noticed. You may be able to get it to converge by giving at least one (probably all three, for symmetry purposes) a finite parallel conductance; that approach has worked for me in the past with SPICE simulations.

Comment: I thank you for your prompt reply.I tried but it did not work, I will try to figure this out.. thank you again